# Interpolate data of a text file (mapreduce)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I have a big text file, every line has a timestamp and some other data, like this:

```
timestamp1,data
timestamp2,data
timestamp5,data
timestamp7,data
...
timestampN,data
```

This file is ordered by timestamp but there might be gaps between consecutive timestamps.
**I need to fill those gaps** and write the new file.

I've thought about reading two consecutive lines of the file. But I have two problems here:

1. How to read two consecutive lines? NLineInputFormat or
   MultipleLineTextInputFormat may help with this, will they read
   line1+line2, line2+line3,... or line1+line2, line3+line4?
2. How to manage lines when I have several mappers running?

Any other algorithm/solution? Maybe this can not be done with mapreduce?

(Pig/Hive solutions are also valid)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar approach to famous [1 Tb sort](http://sortbenchmark.org/YahooHadoop.pdf)
If you know range of timestamp values in your file you can do following:
Mappers should map data by some timestamp region(which will be your key).
Reducers process data in context of one key and you can implement any desired logic there.

Also, [secondary sort](http://codingjunkie.net/secondary-sort/) may help to get values sorted by timestamps in your reducer.

Comment: Please, elaborate your answer because I think that you haven't understood my question... or I don't understand your answer. My problem is how to deal with chunks sent to mappers or reducers when there's a gap between chunks.

Comment: How many images (count and avg size of image) and how many map slots(nodes and avg size of cores) you have?